# Use Enterprise Library Data in WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, enterprise-library

I want to use [Microsofts Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) in a WCF Service (Visual Studio 2010, ASP.net 4.0, VB.net).

But when I enter `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary` it only shows `Common` and "Logging", no `Data`...?

Yes, the Data is referenced :-) This works fine in my asp.net page.

When I try to use `Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` it says:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data' doesn't contain any
>   public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type
>   is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the
>   imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: How are you adding a reference to EntLib ?

Comment: via Nuget. It's working fine in asp.net and also the Logging (added same way via NuGet) works fine.

Comment: Fixed. Previously I used WCF Service Library, now I've recreated it using WCF Service Application and it compiles fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Previously I used WCF Service Library, now I've recreated it using WCF Service Application and it compiles fine. Thanks!